# Sweetalert dialog won't show

Tags: javascript, html, css, dialog, sweetalert

```
window.alert = function (text) {
    swal({
        title: "Computer says:",
        text: text,
        timer: 3000,
        animation: "slide-from-top"
    });
    return true;
};

function run(input) {
    if (input[0] == "alert") {
        ta = input.slice(1, input.length);
        tap = ta.join(" ");
        alert(tap);
    }
}
```

When I call [`run(["alert", "hello"]);` in the javascript console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y1el.gif), it works fine.
But when I [type in `alert hello`, in *my* console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcllf.gif), the dialog briefly flashes and disappears. What is happening here and how do I stop it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It works fine I dont see whats wrong even in console :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweetalert.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.alert = function (text) {
    swal({
        title: "Computer says:",
        text: text,
        timer: 3000,
        animation: "slide-from-top"
    });
    return true;
    };
    function run(input) {
    if (input[0] == "alert") {
        ta = input.slice(1, input.length);
        tap = ta.join(" ");
        alert(tap);
    }
}
run(["alert", "hello"]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I don't change the `window.alert()` function, it works fine but of course the styling dosen't show.

Comment: Maybe your not importing the sweetalert css

Comment: Here is my code for importing: `<script src="dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/sweetalert.css">`

Comment: You have to import css before js